# Elasticsearch mixed number and string multi_match query failing

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a query where I can accept a string containing strings and numbers, and search for those values in fields in my index that contain double values and strings. For example:

Fields: Double doubleVal, String stringVal0, String stringVal1, String doNotSearchVal

Example search string: "person 10"

I am trying to get all documents containing "person" or "10" in any of the fields doubleVal, stringVal0 and stringVal1. This is my example query:

```
{
    "query": {
      "multi_match" : {
        "query": "person 10",
        "fields" : [
          "doubleVal^1.0",
          "stringVal0^1.0",
          "stringVal1^1.0"
        ],
        "type" : "best_fields",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "slop" : 0,
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
}
```

(This query was generated by Spring Data Elastic)

When I run this query, I get this error: (I've removed any identifying information)

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "failed to create query: [query removed]",
                "index_uuid": "index_uuid",
                "index": "index_name"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "index_name",
                "node": "node_value",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to create query: [query removed]",
                    "index_uuid": "index_uuid",
                    "index": "index_name",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "number_format_exception",
                        "reason": "For input string: \"person 10\""
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I do not want to split apart the search string. If there is a way to rewrite the query so that it works in the expected way, I would like to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to set parameter `lenient` to `true`, then format-based errors, such as providing a text query value for a numeric field, will be ignored

You could achieve this in Spring Data with using builder method like this:

`.lenient(true)`